# Convert TIFF to JPEG not working in linux - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation

Tags: java, linux, jpeg, tiff, jai

I have to convert tif files to jpeg (although I've realized that it also fails for converting tif to any extension). My code works properly on my local windows machine but it doesn't work on my dev enviroment (which is a CentOs machine). This is my code (very simple as you could see):

```
public static boolean convertTIFFToJPEG(final File in, final File out) {
    try {
        final PlanarImage image = JAI.create("ImageRead", in);

        final ParameterBlockJAI storeOperation = new ParameterBlockJAI(
                    "FileStore");
        storeOperation.addSource(image);
        storeOperation.setParameter("filename", out.getPath());
        storeOperation.setParameter("format", "jpeg");
        JAI.create("FileStore", storeOperation);
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code works fine in windows, however when I try to execute it on linux I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: - Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation.
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:827)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1395)
    at example.TIFFUtils.convertTIFFToJPEG(TIFFUtils.java:97)
```

If I debug the application, to try to find out something more about the exception, I only get that the cause of it is 'Unable to render RenderedOp for this operation'.

To fix it, I've tried different versions of the Oracle JDK/JRE. Currently I'm using sdk1.6_20, but I also tried the last one and other previous distribution.

On the other hand, I've tried a lot of possibles ways to make the same process (TIFF->JPEG) by using JAI and ImageIO. This one is the code, that I used for ImageIO:

```
public static boolean convertTIFFToJPEG2(final File in, final File out) {
    try {
        ImageOutputStream ios = null;
        ImageWriter writer = null;

        // find an appropriate writer
        Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(JPEG_FORMAT);
        if (it.hasNext()) {
            writer = (ImageWriter)it.next();
        } else {
            return false;
        }

        ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
        writer.setOutput(ios);
        JPEGImageWriteParam writeParam = new JPEGImageWriteParam(Locale.ENGLISH);

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(in);
        IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(image , null, null);

        // write it!
        writer.write(null, iioImage, writeParam);
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And I got the same result: it only works in windows but provokes that exception in linux. In this case the next instructions return null, so the variable 'image' doesn't contain anything.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(tiffFile);
```

Any new idea?

Comment: Are you using OpenJDK or Oracle JDK on linux?

Comment: Could this be a specific problem with some specific TIFFs using a licensed codec?  libtiff only supports the open specification codecs.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for you comment. The compresion of the tiffs that I'm using is "Old JPEG (in TIFF)". I'm going to try to find out if this codec is licenced or not.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think all implementations of JRE (such as OpenJDK) included a Jpeg Encoder that could be used by default in JAI.  I don't know if that's your problem though. Regardless, you might have better success by using the JAI Image IO Tools extension:

- http://java.net/projects/imageio
- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html

This provides integration allowing JAI to use ImageIO libraries for image decoding/encoding which is generally much improved over the original JAI handling.

To further debug your problem, you might try temporary outputting to image format other than JPEG to see if your problem is specific to JPEG encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've only used Oracle JDK/JRE distributions. The one that I'm using now is jdk1.6_20. Regarding to ImageIO, I also made tests using this API, but it didn't work either (in windows it does, but not in linux). I've updated the question with these two issues and the code I used fro ImageIO.